Laravel Set-Cookie Response Header Problem With Cloudflare Cache Mechanism
We have a website built with Laravel 10 (upgraded from Laravel 5.6 to 9, and then to version 10). For this website, we use a load balancer on Cloudflare. However, since we are using the StartSession (\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession) and VerifyCsrfToken (\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken) middleware, the response headers for every page include two Set-Cookie headers. Because of the Set-Cookie headers in the response, Cloudflare prevents the page from being cached and directly serving from the Cloudflare cache for subsequent requests.
How can we resolve this issue to allow Cloudflare to cache the pages while still using the necessary middleware in Laravel?
Cloudflare documentation: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/concepts/cache-control/#conditions

Our website response header:


Keep in mind the CloudFlare cache is for every user and you wouldn't want to cache a page that includes the CSRF token of another user.  I don't see any generic way you can achieve this while still using a Cookie based session and CSRF verification.
